# How to change a field value to NULL when there is a change in another field using mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I am a newbie to mysql. Can anyone please help me to sort out this problem,

"I have the following columns emp id,name,leaveto,leavefrom and status in my table. If an employee applies for leave his manager can accept or reject it. If the manager has accepted the leave then the status filed will contain the value as Approved (same for rejected). What I wanted to know is when the employee applies for leave for the second time the leaveto and leavefrom column gets updated but the status field remains the same. "

Is it possible to make the status field to NULL when there is an update in leaveto and leavefrom columns.

This will update the status field (approve/reject) of an employee by comparing his ID and manager ID. If that employee comes under manager "A" then only manager "A" can approve/reject it.

```
"UPDATE leave_details join managerlogin on managerlogin.manager_id=leave_details.manager_id SET leave_details.leave_status='Approved' where (employee_id='$myemployee_id' and managerlogin.manager_id= '".$_SESSION['mymanager_id']."' )";
```

Comment: Can you please post your code here...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to update the value to NULL.

```
Update tablename set columnname=null where put your condition...
```

Comment: The thing is I need to make it NULL only when the leaveto and leavefrom column value changes (i.e next time when the employee applies leave)

Comment: You should create a separate row for each leave. In this case you will have the history of the leaves the employe has taken. If you update the row then you will not have any history of the leave. So when an employe wants to take a leave a new row should be created with a new leaveid. The status value should be pending. When the manager approve the leave then update the status with the following query:

    Update leave set status='approved' where leaveid=put here the newleave id

Answer (score 0):

You can just

```
update mytable
set status = null,
    leaveto = ...
where emp_id = 17;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to set `NULL` for `Satatus`

```
UPDATE mytable SET status = null WHERE empid = '17'
```

Try it...

---

Put the condition befor Update

```
if($_POST['leavefrom'] || $_POST['leaveto'])
{
    $status == "NULL";
}

UPDATE mytable SET status = '$status' WHERE empid = '17'
```

By using this condition , you can set Null value to Status when leavefrom and leaveto having values.

Comment: How to change the status to NULL when there is a change in leavefrom and leaveto column ?

Comment: Once the employee applied for leave their status should be NULL.. here after someone has been approved. i am right..?

Comment: Yea rite.. When manager approves it the status become "approved". If the employee applies for leave again then the leaveto and leavefrom column changes but not the status field. It remains approved for the second leave. Instead it should also change its value to NUll and wait for manager to approve it. (Or else the employee will think that new leave he has applied for is approved.)